# Set a variable name as the result of another variable in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a variable which gives me a certain value and I would like to use this value as the name of the next variable, tried variable of variables, but couldn't get that to work.

> This variable returns value_name.

```
$field['name'] = isset( $field['name'] ) ? $field['name'] : $field['id'];
```

> Then I would like to use this result as the name of another variable

```
$value_name
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use the name of a variable to define another variable in this way:

```
$field['name'] = isset( $field['name'] ) ? $field['name'] : $field['id'];
$$field['name'] = "your value";

echo $value_name;
```

as you can see you need to use double `$` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it inside curly braces. ${$field['name']}.

```
    $variableName = 'name';

    ${$variableName} = 'something'; //wrapping in curly braces is important

    echo $name;
```

Comment: Just tried it out, I wanted to use that for within html value="<?php echo esc_url( ${$field['name']} ); ?>" . But it's not working